# Disable kids' access to iOS device after 11pm, but also allow parents to remotely and temporarily enable/disable access?

Tags: ios, family-sharing, screen-time

Our teenage kids have been staying up too late on their iPhones, so we'd like to figure out a way to prevent them from using devices after 11PM.  But we'd also like to be able to have a way to temporarily turn this off, e.g. if we know they'll be out late and we want to enable them to text us.

My understanding (correct?) is that we can do everything above via Screen Time, but that disabling Screen Time (temporarily or otherwise) requires physically entering the password on the device. Is there a way to do the disabling/enabling remotely instead? Does Family Sharing do this? If yes, what are the limitations or challenges with Family Sharing for Screen Time control?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to disable anything temporarily for the use case you have described. You can use Screen Time Communication Limits to allow certain contacts, e.g. you, to still be contactable in time periods that are configured to be downtime. See [here](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/set-communication-limits-screen-time-downtime-ios/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Apple implements this in Screen Time. You can set a parental pin to bypass restrictions when needed

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982

Here is an action oriented menu of tips for specific cases for devices intended for children:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304